# Integration of a triangle with fubini's theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I want to calculate a Integration of a triangle with three corners $(0,0),(0,\pi),(\pi,0)$
and the Function is
$f(x,y)=xy-3cos(x+y)$

I used the fubini's theorem to integrate:

$\int_{(0,\pi)}\int_{(0,\pi)}xy-3cos(x+y)dxdy$

and I got $(48+\pi)/4$ as result. But I don't think that's right. How can I get the right result?

Comment: You have integrated over the square with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,\pi)$, $(\pi, 0)$ and $(\pi, \pi)$. Try drawing the region you're integrating over and consider the possible values of $x$ and $y$. If $x$ is some valid value between $0$ and $\pi$, what are the possible values of $y$?

Answer (score 0):

$\int\int xy$$ dxdy =\pi^2 $ and

$\int\int cos(x+y)dxdy=$ $\int\int cos(x)cos(y)-sin(x)sin(y)dxdy=$
$(\int cos(x)dx)^2-(\int sin(x)dx)^2=0-2^2$

$=-4$

So the result is
$\pi^2+12$ when you integrate over the square 
Now we can integrate over a triangle
the equation of the line between (0,\pi) and (\pi,0) is y=-x + \pi$ and so the integral over the triangle is equal to:

$\int_0^\pi(\int_0^{-x+\pi}f(x,y)dy)dx=$
$\int_0^\pi(x(-x+\pi)dx -3$

$\int_0^\pi(cos(x)sin(-x+\pi)+sin(x)(cos(-x+\pi)-1))dx=$
$-\pi^3/3+\pi^2/2+6$

because $sin(-x+\pi)=-sin(-x)=sin(x)$ and $cos(-x+\pi)=-cos(-x)=-cos(x)$

Comment: $f(x,y)=xy-3cos(x+y)$, so the result is $\pi^2+12$?

Comment: Sure sorry you have reason

Comment: thanks... but could you please explain the last two equations?

Comment: Draws the goniometric circumference and observe the relationship between,for example, sin(-\theta) and -sin(\theta) and between  sin(\theta +\pi) and -sin(\theta). You can use this two fondamental relationships to get my two equations